# google picasa web API for obj-C all deprecated?

Tags: ios, google-api

I plan to allow my app to retrieve photos stored in Picasa web albums, what will be the right obj-C compatible API I should use? it appears the XML based obj-C API client is all deprecated... https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list

and the alternative, the JSON based API does not include photo albums...
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

so what should we use now if my humble goal is to get photos from iOS client?